# How to allow Route reqular expression for date and string in laravel

Tags: regex, laravel-5

I want to allow my url as below format but

```
->where(['id'=>'[0-9]+','from'=>'[A-Za-z]+','to'=>'[A-Z]+']);
```

and Sometime I want to access like this

```
 1: /get_acc_customer_info/1/2016-8-1/2016-09-29

2 : /get_acc_customer_info/1/from/to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe `|` to build an alternation:

```
->where([
    'id'   => '[0-9]+',
    'from' => '[A-Za-z]+|\d{4}(?:-\d{1,2}){2}',
    'to'   => '[A-Z]+|\d{4}(?:-\d{1,2}){2}'
]);
```